# stationarity and fractional differencing

Tags: regression, time-series, pca, stationarity, augmented-dickey-fuller

This is a methodology question. I would like to make the data stationary but not transform it "too much" (information loss), before it is fit for statistical/ML purposes such as regression or PCA.

Typical procedure:

1. We inspect the raw time series $x_t$. Assume we see trends or if the ADF test fails, so I seek to transform the data.
2. We check that differencing $x_{t+1} - x_t$ results in stationary series. (Assume it does.)
3. If possible, we seek alternatives to $x_{t+1} - x_t$: the transformation may excessively remove memory from the series. That may help stationarity but at the price of weaker correlations to other series. We therefore use fractional differencing, say with d=0.5, and check that the series is more stationary than the initial series.

Let's apply this to the following series:

[image: Raw series]

Conclude that it is stationary with $95\%$ confidence when using ADF implemented by adfuller() from Python's statsmodels package. The default parameter is $12(n/100)^{1/4}$ where $n$ is the series length. However, we see some (noisy) trend between 2011 and 2016. For the first half of the data the values are almost all negative. I conclude that the data doesn't give enough "labels" for model training.

I am therefore not sure whether the ADF test can be trusted. **Would you feel comfortable using it for regression/PCA?** Now compare with the fractional differencing with $d=0.5$:

[image: Fractional difference]

As expected this makes the series look more stationary. However, it also decreases the correlation to other similar dataset series transformed in the same way. Average correlation decreases as I increase $d$, as can be expected.

I therefore need to choose the smallest $d$ such that I feel comfortable that the transform is stationary. **How do you know when to stop?** I am reluctant to use the ADF pvalue as threshold to automatically set this considering the issue above.

Comment: I am also interested in this question as I am facing exactly the same problem. I hope someone could make light on this.